# Sort hash by values when values are arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash:

```
hash = {"key1" => [1, a], "key2" => [3, c], "key3" => [2, b]}
```

I need to sort the hash by the second element of the values like this:

```
hash = {"key1" => [1, a], "key3" => [2, b], "key2" => [3, c]}
```

How I can do this?

Comment: @Ursus They are ordered as of 1.9. Docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
hash.sort_by { |_k, v| v.last }.to_h
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note here is that as of Ruby 1.9, Ruby hashes are in fact ordered ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html)).

To answer your question, you can use `Enumerable#sort_by` like so:

`hash.sort_by{ |k, v| v[1] }.to_h`

This sorts by the second member of each of the value arrays, and returns it as an array of pairs. Then it converts that array of pairs back into a hash (with `to_h`)

Comment: Ruby 1.9 was released about ten years ago. It's not even maintained anymore. Absolutely no need to mention new features of 1.9. If anyone is sticking to it, its their problem.

Comment: There was a comment on the question saying that hashes are not ordered. That comment has since been deleted, but that’s what I was reacting to.

Comment: It was mine, sorry :D